# Subsets, bijections

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A, B, C$ be sets with $A \subset B \subset C$. Also, let $f : C \to A$ be a bijection. Prove that $\# A=\# B$.

I know that I have to find a bijection $g : B \to A$, but I don't have a clue how to get this one on. I've been looking at this for a while.

Comment: **Hint:** Schröder-Bernstein. There are natural injections $A\to B$ and $B\to C$.